# monacaのinsertCSSでファイルを読み込みたい

Tags: javascript, monaca, css

## 質問内容

monacaのInAppBrowserプラグインを使って、ページを開いたときにcssを書き換えるため、insertCSS関数を使いたいのですがファイルを読み込んでくれないです。
ディレクトリパスが間違えてるのか関数の使い方が間違えてるのかわかりません。
また、fileの部分をcodeにして直書きしたら動きました。
よろしくお願いします。

## ディレクトリ

```
index.html
js/
  index.js
css/
  style.css
```

## jsファイル

```js
function onDeviceReady() {
    var ref = window.open('https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/', '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=no');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function () {
        ref.insertCSS({file: "../css/style.css"});
    });
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getでファイルが読み込まれてから実行しなければならないようです。

```js
$.get('css/style.css', function(cssData) {
    ref.insertCSS( { code: cssData }, function() {
　　　　window.alert("CSS is loaded");
    });
});
```